# Perform a calculation in MVC viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, viewmodel

Trying to perform a calculation in a view model.  I have two donation columns, want to add them together in the viewmodel.

This is in the ViewModel Class:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal ttlDonation
{
  get { return Donation.GetValueOrDefault() + GuestDonation.GetValueOrDefault(); }
}
```

The Viewmodel builds fine, and it displays properly in the razor view using `(modelItem => item.ttlDonation)`. Problem is when I try to SUM this expression with a LINQ query in the controller like so:

```
var DonateTTl = GuestViewModel.Sum(f => f.ttlDonation);
```

Then my code throws an error:

> The specified type member 'ttlDonation' is not supported in LINQ to Entities...

I am wondering the best way to do this.  I also tried this in my controller (below), where I've changed my viewmodel slightly to a basic get; set;  and it still isn't working.   What is the best way to do this?  Should I perform the calculation on my original Model rather than my viewmodel?

```
var GuestViewModel = guests.Select(g => new GuestIndexViewData
{
  ID = g.ID,
  FRID = g.FRID,
  FirstName = g.FirstName,
  LastName = g.LastName,
  Company = g.Company,
  email = g.email,
  Donation = g.Donation,
  GuestFirstName = g.GuestFirstName,
  GuestLastName = g.GuestLastName,
  GuestCompany = g.GuestCompany,
  Guestemail = g.Guestemail,
  GuestDonation = g.Donation,
  Attended = g.Attended,
  RSVP = g.RSVP,
  Guest3 = g.Guest3,
  ttlDonation = (g.GuestDonation.GetValueOrDefault() + g.Donation.GetValueOrDefault())
}).OrderBy(f => f.FRID);

var DonateTTl = GuestViewModel.Sum(f => f.ttlDonation);
```

I know I can find a way to do this but I am looking for the best way to do this as for standards/performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think picking it out will work:

```
var DonateTTl = GuestViewModel.Select(vm => vm.ttlDonation).Sum();
```